# Add additional columns and subqueries to a MySQL VIEW to create more readable version of an existing table

Tags: mysql, sql, view, limesurvey

This problem is really causing me a headache and I have spent hours for different solutions to my problem, but no luck so far.

At our online survey software ("Limesurvey") all data gets stored at a flat table. There is one row for each response data set and each question item has a related column at that table. The actual responses are stored at the table cells. The thing is that this data is hard to read because:

- For array questions Limesurvey just stores the answer code -> we also want to add a column for the full answer text.
- For multiple numeric questions Limesurvey stores the number inputted -> we also want to add a column listing the related sub-question text.

We are trying to achieve the above by creating a MySQL VIEW based on the table definition of the survey's response table. For that we have extended our VIEW feature to add additional columns when creating the VIEW and we have added code to query the related answer and sub-question texts. Those queries work fine, this is what the VIEW shows if ONE data set is inputted (looks good so far):
[One data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6vh4.png)

Thing is that once we add a second data set with different answers, the data gets mixed up. It looks like MySQL just aggregates the data from all rows to fill the additional columns. There are now additional answer/sub-question texts at both rows (marked "?") though for that data set no answer was given, see:
[Two data sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIVwz.png)

My main question is: ***Is it possible to kind of define the scope for the additional "..._TEXT" columns so they get filled based on details of the current row, not the whole data?***

Let me know if you have any questions, it is a little complex to describe this issue.

Comment: For those interested in the underlying SQL code to create the VIEW: http://pastebin.com/xmP27dsH

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.  Using joins like this you can see that you are missing a relationship between the main select and the question columns.  See the comments in my code below.

```
CREATE VIEW lime_view_967824 AS 
  SELECT 
    ls.id 'id',
    ls.submitdate 'submitdate',
    ls.lastpage 'lastpage',
    ls.startlanguage 'startlanguage',
    ls.967824X1087X6950SQ001 'arraySD_SQ001',
    COALESCE(a1.answer,'') AS 'arraySD_SQ001[TEXT]',
    ls.967824X1087X6950SQ002 'arraySD_SQ002',
    COALESCE(a2.answer, '') AS 'arraySD_SQ002[TEXT]',
    ls.967824X1087X6950SQ003 'arraySD_SQ003',
    COALESCE(a3.answer, '') AS 'arraySD_SQ003[TEXT]',
    ls.967824X1087X6946SQ001 'multiOptions_SQ001',
    ls.967824X1087X6946SQ002 'multiOptions_SQ002',
    ls.967824X1087X6946SQ003 'multiOptions_SQ003',
    ls.967824X1087X6946other 'multiOptions_other',
    ls.967824X1087X6941SQ001 'multiNumInput_SQ001',
    COALESCE(q1.question,'') AS 'multiNumInput_SQ001[TEXT]',
    ls.967824X1087X6941SQ002 'multiNumInput_SQ002',
    COALESCE(q2.question,'') AS 'multiNumInput_SQ002[TEXT]',
    ls.967824X1087X6941SQ003 'multiNumInput_SQ003',
    COALESCE(q3.question,'') AS 'multiNumInput_SQ003[TEXT]',
    ls.967824X1087X6941SQ004 'multiNumInput_SQ004',
    COALESCE(q4.question,'') AS 'multiNumInput_SQ004[TEXT]'
  FROM lime_survey_967824 ls
  LEFT JOIN lime_answers a1 ON a1.qid=6950 AND a1.language='en' AND ls.967824X1087X6950SQ001=a1.code
  LEFT JOIN lime_answers a2 ON a2.qid=6950 AND a2.language='en' AND ls.967824X1087X6950SQ002=a2.code
  LEFT JOIN lime_answers a3 ON a3.qid=6950 AND a3.language='en' AND ls.967824X1087X6950SQ003=a3.code
  LEFT JOIN lime_questions q1 ON q1.qid=6941 AND q1.title='SQ001' AND q1.language='en' AND q1.type='K' -- no join to ls?
  LEFT JOIN lime_questions q2 ON q2.qid=6941 AND q2.title='SQ002' AND q2.language='en' AND q2.type='K' -- no join to ls?
  LEFT JOIN lime_questions q3 ON q3.qid=6941 AND q3.title='SQ003' AND q3.language='en' AND q3.type='K' -- no join to ls?
  LEFT JOIN lime_questions q4 ON q4.qid=6941 AND q4.title='SQ004' AND q4.language='en' AND q4.type='K' -- no join to ls?
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am currently traveling but will give this a try when I am back.

So if I get this right, this will lead to the additional columns being updated ONLY based on the data at the related column of the same row, correct?

Comment: @Marcel - that is the idea -- it is using a join instead of a sub-query.  You could also use a single join and a group by, but I always find those harder to read.   If this is slow, there is a way to speed it up with a CTE and proper indexes.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help. This works perfectly for the first part (array questions).
The last part is still causing me a headache because the ...[TEXT] columns should only be filled if the related column (e.g. "967824X1087X6941SQ001" holds a value. It is a numeric data type and the value entered at each cell can be anything between 0 to N. In addition to that, there is no reference between the value stored and the data at the lime_questions table.
Can this be solved at all?

Comment: I have placed the updated SQL at http://pastebin.com/FqJ81NDs. There has beend some not needed code for an additional question and a column was referenced wrongly (had to be "parent_qid" not "qid"). It now fills the [TEXT] columns as well but they are always filled, the scope isn't limited to the current row, see http://imgur.com/a/aoUSo

Comment: @Marcel I have no idea what you want me to solve here -- you say questions are right but the answer are a number... do you then want to join to an answer table that relates those numbers to a string value?  I've don't know. You also say there is no relationship stored between the answer and the question but clearly that relationship is defined in lime_survey since we are using it to make this query and pull both in.

Comment: This is indeed a little hard to explain, so let me first thank you for your patience. Let's focus on that certain "multiple numeric" question type only, here is the updated VIEW code: http://pastebin.com/nZ0u5v9w
The [TEXT] columns get filled with the text taken from "question", all cells get filled BUT the requirement is to only add the text to the additional [TEXT] columns if there was a number entered at the related column. If you check the screenshot at http://imgur.com/a/aoUSo you can see that at the top row the text gets added though the related value is NULL.

Comment: ...continuing my thought above I just added "... AND ls.967824X1087X6941SQ001 IS NOT NULL" to the query and it looks like this was the missing part of the puzzle. I'll continue testing.
Thanks again for your Help, Hogan!

Comment: @Marcel - yes if you want to exclude rows where that value is null that filter would work.